# Excel VBA Error in Listbox populating and unpopulating

Tags: list, vba, excel

I am looking to populate a list box when a check box is ticked and empty it when the tick is removed.

This code worked for this function in my previous modules but now I am getting an error (im guessing it is with the arguments for Range), and I would like to understand why. Additionally, the list box remains as it is when the checkbox is unticked.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        ListBox1.List = Sheets("DATA").Range("C22").Value
    Else
        ListBox1.ListFillRange = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error? Run-time, compile error, just not the expected output?

Comment: So are you trying to set the `ListFillRange` property for a range of cells and/or set the value that is selected in the listbox?

Comment: It is a run time error. Technically, I am trying to set the ListFillRange property to a range of cells that consists of zero cells. This way, I was hoping the listbox would empty out when the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("DATA").Range("C22").Value
    Else
        Me.ListBox1.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is giving me the exact same run time error that I was getting initially. The highlighted line is the line with .Range("C22"). I am wondering why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code to this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    ListBox1.ListFillRange = "C22:C24"
Else
    ListBox1.ListFillRange = ""
End If
End Sub
```

will change the listbox to show the contents of cells C22:C24.